# Magento 2.2.8 : Class Magento\Ui\Block\Wysiwyg\ActiveEditor does not exist

Tags: magento2, backend, class

I have updated from version 2.2.7 to 2.2.8 
now I have this error

> Class Magento\Ui\Block\Wysiwyg\ActiveEditor does not exist

in the back-end when I try to access

for example to Categories page.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

do you find any solution to this error?